# Laravel DOMPDF does not render custom fonts

Tags: laravel, pdf-generation, font-face, dompdf, truetype

I have installed **barryvdh/laravel-dompdf (v0.9.0)** on my **Laravel project (8.43.0)**. I have to print some text on **Bengali**. For that I have tried to install a **custom font (kalpurush)**. I have put the **.ttf** file of the font in **/public/fonts** folder and also **/storage/fonts** folder. I have added the font-face in my pdf generating view like this-

```
<style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'kalpurush';
            src: url("/fonts/kalpurush.ttf") format('truetype');
            }
</style>
```

I have changed the style of the element I want to print like this

```
//Something I want to print written in Bengali

<h5 style='color:red; font-family:kalpurush;'>আমি একজন বাংলাদেশী</h5>
```

But when I try to print the pdf it shows me **??????????** instead of the text in Bengali.

[Error in PDF File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAMlK.png)

Head section of my view is like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="bn">

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Fonts -->
         <style>

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'kalpurush';
            src: url("/fonts/kalpurush.ttf") format('truetype');
            }

        </style>

        <!-- Styles -->
      

    </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there's an [issue.](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/756#issuecomment-756985814)

Use [laravel-pdf](https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf) instead. Read the [custom-fonts](https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf#custom-fonts) section and make sure useOTL and useKashida are enabled.